# Why is my form not validating onsubmit?

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation, onsubmit

I am new at javascript, and am trying to get it so that when a user doesn't fill out all fields on my form, that they get an alert error.

Here is the first line of my form telling it to validate my function on submit...

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="xxxx" class="infusion-form" method="POST" name="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

and here is my javascript function...

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function validateForm() {
    var a = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_FirstName"].value;
    var b = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Email"].value;
    var c = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Phone1"].value;
    var d = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_StreetAddress1"].value;
    var e = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_City"].value;
    var f = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_State"].value;
    var g = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_PostalCode"].value;
    var h = document.forms["myform"]["inf_other_Username"].value;
    var i = document.forms["myform"]["inf_other_Password"].value;
    var j = document.forms["myform"]["inf_other_RetypePassword"].value;

    if (a == null || a == "" || a == "First Name Here") {
        alert("Please enter your First Name!");
        return false;
    }
    if (c == null || c == '' || c == "Enter Your Phone Here" || c.length < 9) {
        alert("Please insert your phone number!");
        return false;
    }
    if (d == null || d == '' || d == "Street Address") {
        alert("Please insert your street address ");
        return false;
    }
if (e == null || e == '' ||e == "City") {
        alert("Please insert your city");
        return false;
    }

    if (f == null || f == '' || f == "State") {
        alert("Please insert your state ");
        return false;
    }

if (g == null || g == '' ||g == "Postal Code") {
        alert("Please insert your postal code");
        return false;
    }
    if (h == null || h == '' || h == "Username") {
        alert("Please insert your username ");
        return false;
    }
if (i == null || i == '' ||i == "password") {
        alert("Please insert your password");
        return false;
    }
    if (j == null || j == '' || j == "password") {
        alert("Please re - type your password ! ");
        return false;
    }




    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (document.myform.inf_field_Email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        return false;
    }
}
// ]]>
</script>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? thank you so much for any help. Also the page is at http://business.uglyopportunities.com/affiliate-signup/ if you want to inspect element (form is located at bottom of page)

thanks

Comment: can you post your full html form code part

Comment: Not the problem, but you should be able to remove those `x == null` tests because the `.value` property shouldn't ever return `null`. Double-check the field names - if there's a typo in one then it (obviously) won't be found and then trying to access its `.value` property will cause an error.

Comment: nitpick: Single letter variable names are bad! Store the reference of `document.forms["myform"]` into a variable and use that as a look up. e.g. `var frm = document.forms["myform"]; var fName = frm["inf_field_FirstName"].value;` Also value is not going to be null on an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare validateForm in javascript AFTER the form. Try moving it up to before the form. Or even better, in the head of your page.

Learn how to use a javascript debugger. You would have caught this right away (validateForm throws an error when called).  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54IgWgoFToc

Comment: I would probably declare the function in the `<head>`, but it shouldn't matter where the function is declared given that it likely won't be called until the whole page is loaded anyway (given the submit event is - presumably - in response to the user clicking something). That is, at the time that that `onclick` is triggered the function will exist.

Comment: Hi thank you very much mrtsherman I tried putting the script before the form, but that did not work.  However when I put it within the head tags it now works like a charm thank you very much for your time.